# Is it possible to replace AliceBox DSL by any modem router

Tags: router, dsl, modem

This alice box (O2) is used only in germany so it might have contry dependent specifications.

For home use, I would like to replace the standard Alice DSL box by a linksys WRT54GL, which is a very configurable router, in order to use the Quality of Service (QoS) function (OS will be tomato I think).

This QoS is needed because excessive video streaming makes me unable to play any online game with reasonable ping (>250ms).

I've noticed that there is some strange PIN for "Alice IAD Freischalten". I understood the connection had to be "unlocked", so I don't know if you can replace the device because of this restriction.

My subquestions are:
1- is it possible to directly replace this router by the linksys
1.1- if yes: will I be able to connect my telephon to it ?
1.2 if no, will QoS work with this structure: ISP > aliceDSLBox(192.168.1.x) > WRT54GL(192.168.0.x) > computers LAN and WLAN

thanks a lot for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I separated two networks:
AliceBox(192.168.0.x) which connects to the internet, and transmits ONLY to the WRT(192.168.1.x). The router forwards internet connection to all computers.

I activated QoS by installing TomatoUSB firmware on the WRT. It took a long time through reading guides and ajdusting parameters for a proper use.

Finally, I solved my ping problem, excepted in the case of massive VOIP and skype("like") messaging, which does not happen often.
I can play games, and housemate call family,stream and endlessly watch youtube:)